# Disabling WCF metadata exchange from the client side

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

I have a Service Reference that I am using in my console application to make various webservice calls. This webservice is very large and has hundreds of methods.

I noticed that the first call to this webservice takes very very long (2+ minutes) and thought I'd do some investigation as to why. I found this article that seems to narrow it down to metadata exchange.

http://www.synergex.com/blog/2015/06/25/why-is-that-first-wcf-operation-so-slow/

From what I can tell, it only shows you how to disbale metadata exchange on the Webservice side and not from the client side. How do I disable this exchange of metadata from the clientside?

PS:
Please note that c# is not my main language. I need the answer to be quite specific :)

Comment: MetaData exchange is controlled by the service - the client can't disable it.   The best option in your case (if you don't have access to the service code and/or config) would be to create a channel factory instance upon application startup and cash it, then generate new communication channels (connections) from the cached channel factory.

Comment: Tim, metadata is used in the initial code generation when adding a Service Reference. I'm not asking to turn off the ability of the server side to exchange the metadata, I am asking how do I tell my client to not request it at runtime as you dont need it at runtime.

Comment: When something does not work in WCF as you expect the first advice is always to enable logs and check where time is spent. It could be metadata, it could also be security negotiation, it can be something else. So enable logs and check where time is spent. See guidelines here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging